# mysql can't insert record with unsigned primary key being zero

Tags: mysql, insert

I am trying to insert one record into dim_channel table with zero for the primary key (unsigned int).

Mysql command:

```
INSERT INTO dim_channel 
set channel_id=0,name='Other',parent_channel_id=0,parent_channel_name='Other';
```

Results:

```
select * from dim_channel;
+------------+-------+-------------------+---------------------+
| channel_id | name  | parent_channel_id | parent_channel_name |
+------------+-------+-------------------+---------------------+
|          1 | Other |                 0 | Other               |
+------------+-------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

Please note that channel_id got value 1, not 0 as I expected.

Any one knows why this happens.

By the way, I can update the record as:
update dim_channel set channel_id=0 where channel_id=1;

Just want to know why I can't insert the record with channel_id=0 at the first place.

Thanks a lot.

====== MySQL command for you to test ====

-- Create table

```
CREATE TABLE `dim_channel` (
  `channel_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` char(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_channel_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `parent_channel_name` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`channel_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

-- insert record

```
INSERT INTO dim_channel set channel_id=0,name='Other',parent_channel_id=0,parent_channel_name='Other';
```

-- see result

```
select * from dim_channel;
```

Comment: mysql assumes 0 means "give me the next ID" for auto_increment columns.  If you really really want a 0 where it doesn't belong, then use an update after the insert.

Comment: @user645280  great comment!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is because you have an auto-increment primary key on that field.  If you assign `NULL` or `0` for that value on insert it will explicitly give you the next number in the sequence for the table.

Comment: Thanks. Seems I have to use two mysql commands to insert this record.

Comment: @user1828513 Note that if your intention is to be able to enter `0` as the value for multiple records, you will not be able to have a primary key or non-null unique index on this field. I would certainly think about why you are doing this in the first place and think about whether setting an auto-increment primary key field value to 0 is really the best approach to represent whatever it is you are trying to represent in your data.

Comment: @MikeBrant hope he doesnt wanna insert 0 into multiple rows, doing so would TOTALLY break the concept of 'id'

Answer (score 55):

I know this is an old post but anyhow:

Use:

```
SET sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
```

before inserting the 0 value in your Dimensions.

Comment: Very helpful. For future reference, would this be set in the SQL that's being executed, or can you set this as a permanent configuration option in MySQL?