# Insert zero as PK for table with auto-increment primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with an auto-increment primary key.  I have a special case need to have a record with a PK value of zero.  Based on [mysql can't insert record with unsigned primary key being zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549566/mysql-cant-insert-record-with-unsigned-primary-key-being-zero), I see I can do so by executing `SET sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';` before the insert.

In another session where this flag will not be set, I want to be able to utilize the default auto-increment functionality by inserting `0` or `NULL`.

Will there be any horrific consequences for doing this?

Comment: It should be easy to run two queries yourself. I assume it won't affect the second session, once the row is inserted. auto_increment will insert new rows with the sequence of values

Comment: @knittl  Thanks.  I read some other posts which indicated that doing so is not a good idea, and didn't know whether some unforeseen disaster would occur.