# Can't add foreign key to table MariaDB/MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I'm creating tables in MariaDB 10.6 database for TPC-H benchmark.
`CREATE TABLE` works ok, but adding `FOREIGN KEY` fails.
I tried following [mariadbtutorial](https://www.mariadbtutorial.com/mariadb-basics/mariadb-foreign-key/) and [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/foreign-keys/) but this doesn't work too.

I suspect:

- syntax of `FOREIGN KEY` is wrong
- Wrong datatype in column that reference foreign key.
- column refering to foreign key should be index
- there's something wrong with data generated by dbgen from TPC-H benchmark.

The errors that occured:

- warning 150:   *alter table `bazatest2`.`nation` with foreign key (N_REGIONKEY) constraint failed. field type or character set for column 'N_REGIONKEY' does not match referenced column 'R_REGIONKEY'.*
  Tried changing `BIGINT NOT NULL` to `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL`
  but different error occurs:
- error 1452 when i tried adding `UNSIGNED` to `BIGINT` in column that should refer to foreign key.

Part of file containing creates:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS NATION CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE NATION (
    N_NATIONKEY     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    N_NAME          CHAR(25),
    N_REGIONKEY     BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  -- references R_REGIONKEY
    N_COMMENT       VARCHAR(152)
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS REGION CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE REGION (
    R_REGIONKEY SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    R_NAME      CHAR(25),
    R_COMMENT   VARCHAR(152)
);
```

Part of file with foreign key constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE NATION ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (N_REGIONKEY) REFERENCES REGION(R_REGIONKEY);
```

I tried solving this by changing syntax of alter table add constraint foreign key and searching for solutions all yesterday and haven't found solution.
Most likely is that column referencing to foreign key should be index, or multiple errors,
but I don't know what should i change in my code.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, simplify! I.e. remove all tables/columns/fk's not needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @jarlh to reproduce problem (1 of 7, but they are identical) you need only create table nation, create table region and last alter table.

Comment: Since you know what's needed, you can remove the rest of the stuff from the question.

Comment: @WojciechCode problem in SERIAL is an alias for BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE. Change data type To BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: Not reproduced. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=2f4527694e4db2b4bc24f8437a526769

Comment: @Piyush Kachhadiya data is imported from file with records separated by '|', I checked and it already contains numbers in these column. Should BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL still have AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: @Akina share example please see in link.

Comment: What link to you tell about?

Comment: part of file with data that is loaded to table nation:   1|ALGERIA|0| haggle. carefully final deposits detect slyly agai|
2|ARGENTINA|1|all foxes promise slyly according to the regular accounts. bold requests alon|
3|BRAZIL|1|alongside of the pending deposits. carefully special packages are about the ironic forges.|

Comment: If you can't answer please upvote, so other people can help me.

Comment: @Piyush Kachhadiya Tried BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT and I get :  ERROR 1075 (42000) at line 3 in file: 'C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents\benchmark\createnation.sql': Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: With BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL another error occurs: ERROR 1452 (23000) at line 12 in file: 'C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents\benchmark\createnation.sql': Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bazatest2`.`nation`, CONSTRAINT `nation_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`N_REGIONKEY`) REFERENCES `region` (`R_REGIONKEY`))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all answers,
I added UNSIGNED to BIGINT, but it wasn't main source of my problem.
The problem was that I imported data from file where primary key values started at 0.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549566/mysql-cant-insert-record-with-unsigned-primary-key-being-zero) I found that in MariaDB/MySQL if 0 is given for primary key, it will automatically assign first value. It changed
0, 1, 2 to 1, 1, 2 and error occured.
There are two options:

- changing settings of dbgen (program generating data for TPC-H benchmark).
  Possible options are: INFORMIX, DB2, TDAT (Teradata), SQLSERVER, SYBASE, ORACLE, VECTORWISE. Options stand for database syntax, by there is no MYSQL option.
  dbgen creates '|' separated file (.tbl) with records for this tables.
  I used ORACLE and it generated file with primary keys starting at 0.
  You can comment if you know which option would be most similar to MySQL syntax and contain keys starting at 0.
- Or is there any automatic software which will add 1 to primary keys in this file. Although NATION and REGION tables are not so big (20, 5), some other tables (which I removed from this question for clarity) will have over 100 000 records.

Answer (score 0):

syntax is wrong, use this

```
ALTER TABLE NATION ADD CONSTRAINT NATION_FK FOREIGN KEY (N_REGIONKEY) REFERENCES REGION(R_REGIONKEY);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it